# @EnableZuulProxy doesnot work due to `HttpServletRequest` class not found

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, netflix-zuul

I am writing a `Zuul` enabled API gateway for my microservices,
However while starting the the microservice containing `zuul`, I am getting the below mentioned error

> Error: **Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:**
>   **javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest**

After numerous search, I have found below two solutions which does not help me. Hence I am here

1. Enable the `Apache tomcat facet`. This for some reason disabled in `Dynamic web module 3.0`.
2. Creating custom `dispatcher servlet`. But this solution should be feasible when we use servlet 2.5.

Since I am using a spring-boot app imported from `https://spring.io`, so it cements that I am using `servlet 3.0`.

My API gateway `pom.xml`:

```
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

I have annotated my API gateway class with `@EnableZuulProxy`.

Having said these could you please help me with my error highlighted above.

> Edit:  When I change the 
>   1. `spring-starter-parent` to **1.5.3RELEASE** instead of the latest.
>   2. `spring-cloud.version` to **Edgware.SR2** from **Finchley.SR1**. I face no issue at all.

I guess it is latest spring thing ? Any thoughts!

Comment: Likely a corrupted JAR download. Can wipe out all of your `/.m2/repository` folder, or try and find the particular jar(s), I would personally just delete the `org.springframework` folder and run a `mvn install` or can run `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository`

Comment: How are you starting the application? From IDE or command line?

Comment: @galovics from IDE

Comment: What about running the application with maven? `mvn spring-boot:run`

Answer (score 1):

I have tried simplifying your pom and I am not getting any issue.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zuul</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Let me know after putting these dependency, it is still not working. Can you also provide githhb link for your source code

Comment: what spring-starter-parent version did you use ?

Comment: 1.5.3.RELEASE and 2.0.0.RELEASE

Comment: Could be an issue with multiple versions of the same dependencies?

Comment: The dependancies mention in your pom.xml is being hard to find. It shows error that the jars are misisng while maven building it.

Comment: `spring-cloud-starter-zuul/eureka` are present with spring 1.5.3. They are not compatible with spring 2.0.3. As I have already mentioned, my code is already fine with spring 1.5.3. I guess with spring 2.0.3, something is amiss.

Comment: Can you try with latest 2.0.4.RELEASE, if you still get problem, you should raise a ticket with spring team
Meanwhile can you please put your code in git hub so that I can have a look

Comment: Hey Vivek. Have a look at https://github.com/sagar-patro/demo-microservices/tree/master/before/citi-eureka-server